# Difference between "Pass" vs "give" a smile

Tags: american-english, spoken-english

Which one's correct?

- When i played with the baby, she passed a smile   or
- When I played with the baby , she gave a smile.

Comment: Pls describe what you are trying to say. Neither makes a lot of sense as is.

Comment: @user3169 When "I played with baby, she smiled at me" maybe ??

Comment: If you search online for "pass a smile", do you find anything?

Comment: @user3169 - Actually, yes, but it sounds weird and is (in my opinion) why you shouldn't use things just because you saw them somewhere on the internet.

Comment: @stangdon I didn't mean automatically accept what you find, but consider whether such usages seem OK or not. And these can certainly be added to a question. But if you can't find good examples, the usage is probably questionable at best.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

All of these work:

> She smiled.
>
> She gave me a smile.
>
> A smile showed on her face.

Passed a smile wouldn't be correct, but `passed me a smile` is grammatically correct (albeit awkward).